# bash/sed: producing 2D bar plots from multi-column data

Tags: bash, sed, xmgrace

I am dealing with the analysis of multi-column data organized in the following manner:

```
#Acceptor                DonorH           Donor   Frames         Frac      AvgDist       AvgAng
lig_608@O1            GLU_166@H       GLU_166@N    13731       0.6865       2.8609     160.4598
lig_608@O2          HIE_163@HE2     HIE_163@NE2     8320       0.4160       2.8412     150.3665
lig_608@N2         ASN_142@HD21     ASN_142@ND2     1575       0.0788       2.9141     157.3493
lig_608@N2           THR_25@HG1      THR_25@OG1      218       0.0109       2.8567     156.0376
lig_608@O1         GLN_189@HE22     GLN_189@NE2       72       0.0036       2.8427     157.3778
lig_608@N2         ASN_142@HD22     ASN_142@ND2       43       0.0022       2.9093     165.3063
lig_608@N2            SER_46@HG       SER_46@OG       32       0.0016       2.8710     159.8673
lig_608@F1           HIE_41@HE2      HIE_41@NE2       31       0.0015       2.8904     153.0763
lig_608@O2           SER_144@HG      SER_144@OG       20       0.0010       2.8147     144.6951
lig_608@N2           THR_24@HG1      THR_24@OG1       16       0.0008       2.8590     165.3937
lig_608@O2            GLY_143@H       GLY_143@N       15       0.0008       2.8729     149.1930
lig_608@F1         GLN_189@HE22     GLN_189@NE2       15       0.0008       2.9192     146.2273
lig_608@O2            SER_144@H       SER_144@N       10       0.0005       2.9259     148.8008
lig_608@N2             THR_26@H        THR_26@N        8       0.0004       2.9491     149.1861
lig_608@O2            GLU_166@H       GLU_166@N        4       0.0002       2.8839     150.1238
lig_608@N2         GLN_189@HE21     GLN_189@NE2        3       0.0001       2.9567     153.7993
lig_608@N2         ASN_119@HD21     ASN_119@ND2        2       0.0001       2.8564     147.7916
lig_608@O2            CYS_145@H       CYS_145@N        2       0.0001       2.8867     151.6423
lig_608@O1         GLN_189@HE21     GLN_189@NE2        2       0.0001       2.8888     148.3678
lig_608@N2            GLY_143@H       GLY_143@N        2       0.0001       2.9658     149.2518
lig_608@F1         GLN_189@HE21     GLN_189@NE2        1       0.0001       2.8675     139.9754
lig_608@F1            GLN_189@H       GLN_189@N        1       0.0001       2.8987     168.1758
lig_608@N2           HIE_41@HE2      HIE_41@NE2        1       0.0001       2.9411     147.0443
```

From this I need to take into account the info from the third column (donor) as well as the fifth column (Frac) and print the 2D histogram of the data taking into account the values (of the fifth column) bigger then 0.01. So in the demonstrated example, only the following data should be considered:

```
#Donor                #Frac
GLU_166@N              0.6865 
HIE_163@NE2            0.4160
ASN_142@ND2            0.0788
THR_25@OG1             0.0109
```

and the 2D histogram should plot # Donor on X and #Frac on Y (in %)

Before I had to add the following lines to the reduced 2D datafile in order that it could be recognized by gracebat as 2D bar plot:

```
@    title  "No tittle"
@    xaxis  label "Donor"
@    yaxis  label "Frac"
@s0 line type 0
@TYPE bar
# here is the data in 2 column format
```

Is it possible to automatize such file post-processing to produce the bar plot on-the-fly ? alternatively I would be grateful for sed solution to edit the datafile on the fly to reduce it to 2 columns and insert in the begining @ lines required for bar graph ploting using:

```
sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' datafile
```

Comment: You should look into AWK. It makes it easy to work with columnar data and it offers facilities for printing text before/after the processed input (`BEGIN`/`END` sections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` isn't meant for this kind of task, you should use `awk`:

```bash
awk  '
    BEGIN {
        print "@ title \"No title\""
        print "@ xaxis label \"Donor\""
        print "@ yaxis label \"Frac\""
        print "@s0 line type 0"
        print "@TYPE bar"
    }
    NR > 1 && $5 > 0.01 { print $3, $5 }
' file.txt
```

Comment: thank you! just a questions:  is it possible to ignore header (the first line) from the original file or to put # slash before it thus producing #Donor Frac in the output ?

Comment: @JamesStarlight the header is discarded by the `$5 > 0.01` condition (the numerical value of the literal string `Frac` is `0`). If you want to add a `#Donor Frac` line then you can do it in the `BEGIN` block

Comment: in fact, I've just tested your script in the output the line Donor Frac (without #) is always present inspite of the condition (I also thought about it!)

Comment: @JamesStarlight You're right, `awk` is doing a string comparison; I updated my answer for filtering out the first line

Comment: thank you very much! now I have a question regarding the visualisation of the plot using gracebat :-) you will be welcome to share your ideas as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with an on-the-fly generated Gnuplot script, e.g.:

```
cat <<EOS | gnuplot > output.png
set term pngcairo size 1280,960
set xtics noenhanced
set xlabel "Frac"
set ylabel "Donor"
set key off
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9
plot "<awk 'NR == 1 || \$5 > 0.01' infile.tsv" using 0:5:xtic(3) with boxes
EOS
```

Which results in a png file:
[image: Bar graph of requested table]

Comment: Thank you very much for this fantastic sollution! one question: would it be possible to add on the resulted graph the name of the infile.tsv ?? In my case it is directly stored in the bash variable ${file_name2} which execute this awk script

Comment: @JamesStarlight: just replace `output.png` with your variable

Comment: this is how to provide output path of the file, e.g. I changed ti to gnuplot > ${output}/${file_name2}.png    my question was rather would it be possible to display on the gnuplot graph the name of the original log file from which the graph was computed ?

Comment: Add `set title "$file_name"` to the Gnuplot script

Comment: I gotcha! here is my another question about customization of the graph, you are welcome to contribute! :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961783/gnuplot-awk-ploating-bar-graph-for-filtered-data