# gnuplot/ awk: ploating bar graph for filtered data

Tags: plot, awk, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot combined with AWK to plot 2D bar plot from the following input data:

```
#Acceptor                DonorH           Donor   Frames         Frac      AvgDist       AvgAng
lig_608@O3          HIE_163@HE2     HIE_163@NE2      498       0.5304       2.8317     153.0580
lig_608@O             GLU_166@H       GLU_166@N      476       0.5069       2.8858     161.7174
lig_608@O1           HIE_41@HE2      HIE_41@NE2      450       0.4792       2.8484     158.5193
THR_26@O             lig_608@H9      lig_608@N1      399       0.4249       2.8312     149.9578
lig_608@O2             THR_26@H        THR_26@N      312       0.3323       2.9029     164.8033
lig_608@O1         ASN_142@HD21     ASN_142@ND2       14       0.0149       2.8445     158.4224
lig_608@O1         GLN_189@HE22     GLN_189@NE2        2       0.0021       2.8562     149.7421
lig_608@O1         GLN_189@HE21     GLN_189@NE2        1       0.0011       2.7285     158.4377
lig_608@O3            GLY_143@H       GLY_143@N        1       0.0011       2.7421     147.8213
```

My script takes the data from the third and 5th columns considering only the lines where the value from the 5th column > 0.05, producing bar graph

```
cat <<EOS | gnuplot > graph.png
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set xtics noenhanced
set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"
set key off
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9
plot "<awk 'NR == 1 || \$5 > 0.05' $file" using 0:5:xtic(3) with boxes
EOS
```

**!EDITED:**
within my bash workflow the script looks like

```
for file in "${output}"/${target}*.log ; do
 file_name3=$(basename "$file")
 file_name2="${file_name3/.log/}"
 file_name="${file_name2/${target}_/}"
echo "vizualisation with Gnuplot!"
cat <<EOS | gnuplot > ${output}/${file_name2}.png
set title "$file_name" font "Century,22" textcolor "#b8860b"
set tics font "Helvetica,12"
#set term pngcairo size 1280,960
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set yrange [0:1]
set xtics noenhanced
set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"
set key off
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9
plot "<awk 'NR == 1 || \$5 > 0.05' $file" using 0:5:xtic(3) with boxes
EOS
done
```

[image]

This is the image produced from following filtered data:

```
HIE_163@NE2 0.5304
GLU_166@N 0.5069
HIE_41@NE2 0.4792
lig_608@N1 0.4249
THR_26@N 0.3323
```

> I need to modify my awk searching expression integrated in the
> gnuplot that makes selection of the two columns from the whole data.
> Instead of taking the index from the third column (Donor) from each
> line I need to take it either from the first (#Acceptor) or form the
> third (#Donor) column. The index should be taken from one of these
> columns depending on the lig_* pattern. E.g. if the data in the
> (#Acceptor) column starts from lig* I need to take the value from the
> third column (#Donor) of the same line and visa verse (lig* pattern
> presents either in the 1st column or in the 3rd but not in the both..)
> Taking my example, the filtered data with the updated searching should become:

```
HIE_163@NE2 0.5304 # the first index from the third column
GLU_166@N 0.5069 # the first index from the third column
HIE_41@NE2 0.4792 # the first index from the third column
THR_26@O 0.4249 # !!!! the first index from the first column !!
THR_26@N 0.3323 # the first index from the third column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you potentially want to do more complicated processing with `awk`, I would
suggest an alternative way of mixing `awk` and `gnuplot`.

Gnuplot supports including inline data in its script files, so you could have awk generate the inline data while supplying the plot-configuration with `bash`, all done in a sub-shell. For example:

```bash
(
printf '$data << EOD\n'

awk 'NR>1 && $5>0.05 { print $1 ~ /^lig/ ? $3 : $1, $5 }' infile

cat << EOS
EOD

set term pngcairo size 1280,960 font ",20"
set output "output.png"

set xtics noenhanced
set ytics 0.02
set grid y
set key off

set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9

set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"

plot "\$data" using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, "" using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0,1
EOS
)
```

Would produce this gnuplot script:

```
$data << EOD
HIE_163@NE2 0.5304
GLU_166@N 0.5069
HIE_41@NE2 0.4792
THR_26@O 0.4249
THR_26@N 0.3323
EOD

set term pngcairo size 1280,960 font ",20"
set output "output.png"

set xtics noenhanced
set ytics 0.02
set grid y
set key off

set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9

set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"

plot "$data" using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, "" using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0,1
```

Pipe it to Gnuplot, i.e. `(...) | gnuplot` and get this in `output.png`:
[image]

Comment: could you precise if it would be possible to use a bash variable inside the gnuplot sctipt e,g to print the filename directly on the graph. For example set title "$file_name" font "Century,22" textcolor "#b8860b"   print "$file_name" ;-)

Comment: also, this part does not work , "" using 0:(\$2+.01):2 with labels

Comment: @JamesStarlight: Did you try using a bash variables in the heredoc? It works as you would expect.

"does not work" how?  the `using with labels` and offset calculation works here. Try running it with `LC_ALL=C` infront of the gnuplot command. Anyway I updated it to use `offset` instead.

Comment: Right, thank you it works very well! I've just tried to improve the pipeline adding sort after AWK and it works very well. just a question: what is the difference between <( cat <<'EOG' and  cat << EOS ? I mean only in the second case I could use bash variables directly in the gnuplot script, e.g. set title "$file_name

Comment: @JamesStarlight: heredocs require the same start and end, here are some more examples: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/

Answer (score 2):

No need for awk, you can do it all in gnuplot (hence platform-independent).
This would be my first attempt. You will filter by plotting the unwanted data at x-value of `NaN`, however, this will give some warnings: `warning: add_tic_user: list sort error` which you can ignore.
But this can probably be avoided by some changes.

***Edit:** the original script would have failed when the first line had a value <0.05 in column 5. Here are two versions which don't have this problem. There will also be no warnings. Maybe these attempts can be further simplified.*

For creating an output file simply add this to your script: (check `help output`)

```
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set output "myOutputFile.png"

...<your script>...

set output
```

**Data:** `SO73961783.dat`

```
#Acceptor                DonorH           Donor   Frames         Frac      AvgDist       AvgAng
lig_608@O3          HIE_163@HE2     HIE_163@NE2      498       0.5304       2.8317     153.0580
lig_608@O             GLU_166@H       GLU_166@N      476       0.5069       2.8858     161.7174
lig_608@O1           HIE_41@HE2      HIE_41@NE2      450       0.4792       2.8484     158.5193
THR_26@O             lig_608@H9      lig_608@N1      399       0.4249       2.8312     149.9578
lig_608@O2             THR_26@H        THR_26@N      312       0.3323       2.9029     164.8033
lig_608@O1         ASN_142@HD21     ASN_142@ND2       14       0.0149       2.8445     158.4224
lig_608@O1         GLN_189@HE22     GLN_189@NE2        2       0.0021       2.8562     149.7421
lig_608@O1         GLN_189@HE21     GLN_189@NE2        1       0.0011       2.7285     158.4377
lig_608@O3            GLY_143@H       GLY_143@N        1       0.0011       2.7421     147.8213
```

**Script 1:**

Filter your data and write it into a new table. If condition >0.05 is not met, write an empty line. Probably the easiest to understand and gives the shortest final plot command.

```
### conditional xtic labels
reset session
set termoption noenhanced 

FILE = "SO73961783.dat"

set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"
set key off
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9
set grid y
set xrange[-1:5]

set table $Filtered
    myTic(col1,col2) = strcol(col1)[1:3] eq 'lig' ? strcol(col2) : strcol(col1)
    plot FILE u ((y0=column(5))>0.05 ? sprintf("%g %s",y0,myTic(1,3)) : '') w table
unset table

plot $Filtered u 0:1:xtic(2) w boxes
### end of script
```

**Script 2:**

Without extra table, but a more complex plot command. Increase the x-position `x0` if a value>0.05 is found (except for the first time) and keep the previous position and and label (i.e. overwrite it) if a value<=0.05 is found.

```
### conditional xtic labels
reset session
set termoption noenhanced

FILE = "SO73961783.dat"

set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"
set key off
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9
set grid y
set xrange[-1:5]

myTic(col1,col2) = strcol(col1)[1:3] eq 'lig' ? strcol(col2) : strcol(col1)

plot x0=c=(t0='',0) FILE u ((y0=column(5))>0.05 ? (c==0 ? (c=1,t0=myTic(1,3)) : (x0=x0+1,t0=myTic(1,3))) : (y0=NaN),x0):(y0):xtic(t0) w boxes
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The return value of the myTic function returns a string of column data, but should return an integer representing the column number to pass the value to xtic().

Comment: @binzo in principle yes, but have you tried instead `myTic(col1,col2) = strcol(col1)[1:3] eq 'lig' ? col2 : col1`? Although the function is returning a column number it will not place the xtic from the corresponding column, for some reason which is not fully clear to me. The argument of `xtic()` may also contain a string.

Comment: hey many thanks for this elegant sollution! would it be possible to show a version of the script which load a file (from bash) and save it e.g. using file.png as it was shown in my first example? Actually this is my first experience with the gnuplot so ..

Comment: @JamesStarlight actually, I just noticed that the current script above will fail if the first line of your list has a value<0.05 in the 5th column. I will add a more robust solution, and also from input file to output file.

Comment: thank you! may you just show a one more example in the similar format which I demonstrated in my first topic beginining with cat <<EOS | gnuplot > output.png in order that I could understand how to manipulate it within my bash workflow?

Comment: @JamesStarlight sorry, I am not familiar with bash. I would have to make wild guesses which I cannot test myself since (so far) I am not working under Linux.

Comment: right, thank you! I've just updated my first topic demonstrating how it works in the linux shell :-)

Comment: @JamesStarlight probably you can do it all in gnuplot. But I do not fully understand what your bash script is actually doing. Maybe plotting all `.log` files in a directory and create `.png` files for each of them. Then this is maybe be helpful if you want to do it in gnuplot: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67716946/7295599

Comment: hey, finally I could integrate you first version in my bash workflow and it seems to me that it works. just one question would it be possible to add the Y values directly above the bars on the plot (e.g. in the first version) ? ;-)

Comment: @JamesStarlight there are a few examples here on SO. In your case something like `plot $Filtered u 0:1:xtic(2) w boxes, '' 0:1:1 w labels offset 0,1`.

Comment: gnuplot> plot $Filtered u 0:1:xtic(2) w boxes, '' 0:1:1 w labels offset 0,1
                                                  ^
         line 0: unexpected or unrecognized token

Comment: @JamesStarlight sorry, I forgot the `using` or `u` in the second plot command:  `plot $Filtered u 0:1:xtic(2) w boxes, '' u 0:1:1 w labels offset 0,1`

Comment: Thank you very much my fried! I have another question related to gnuplot visualisation of bar plots but I will create a new topic in order thet you may share there with your experiences

Comment: here it's, I believe the question might be very trivial for person experienced with gnuplot :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976330/gnuplot-sort-bars-on-the-bar-graphs